# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quote') at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload

Tags: json, undefined

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `
    "${quotes[randomNum].quote}" - ${quotes[randomNum].character} <br>
    ${quotes[randomNum].pic}
    `;
  }
}
```

i didn't think I need to define quote because its in my json

Comment: log `randomNum` and check it corresponds to a valid property (index?) of `quotes`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.